# Core Data batch size

Tags: core-data

I'm new to Core Data. I'm working against a large database, so batching/faulting mechanism is important to me.

I understand how this works when using an NSFetchedResultsController paired with a UITableView, but what if I'm not using this pairing, i.e. what if I'm allowing users to navigate sequentially through a detail view controller (similar to how Apple's Mail program does it at the message level)?

Right now, I load the sorted fetch results into an NSArray and can traverse that as needed.  But if I limit the batch size to 20 for the fetched results, what do I do when the user wants to navigate to object # 21?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While NSFetchedResultsController is designed to be used with a UITableView, you can still use it stand alone.

When creating a fetch request, setLimit determines how many total objects are returned. setBatchSize determines how many of those objects are un-faulted at a time. So, initially, all but the first 20 objects retrieved will be returned as faults. When you access item 21, it will fetch (un-fault) another 20 objects in the results set.

Comment: I was aware of this as an option, but was cautioned it was a resource-heavy mechanism to use when a UITableView wasn't required. Do you share this opinion, or do you feel the convenience outweighs the cost?  Also, what is the mechanism for navigating a FetchedResultsController without a table, i.e. when paired with a table, the act of scrolling past the current batch of records presumably fires the next batch of faults.  But if I access fetchedObjects directly and just start iterating through it directly, what will trigger the next batch?  Won't the MOC simply fault each object as it requires?

Comment: In addition to managing sections, a fetched results controller does change tracking for it's underlying MOC and can also implement caching. You can be advised of changes by becoming the delegate of the FRC. It can also do caching of the last results set. However, the batching behavior described above is not limited to using a FRC.

Comment: First, thanks for taking so much time to answer my questions, but I'm still not clear about one thing.  Say I have a ViewController that presents my objects one at a time using Next/Prev buttons.  If I use an array to hold the first batch of results from my fetch request, I simply monitor where I am in the array index, and if want to go past the end of the first batch, I use fetchOffSet to fire the faults of the next batch of objects.  That's pretty straightforward.  But if use a FetchResultsController, how would I manage this task any differently re: navigation and fetching that next batch?

Comment: Actually, I just did some additional reading/experimentation, and I think I understand.  As Scott tried to tell me above, setBatchSize only affects how many objects will have their faults fired; setLimit affects how many objects are retrieved.  So, if my query returns 1,000 objects and my batch size is 20, the array will contain all 1,000 objects; it's just that they'll all be faulted except for the first 20.  In terms of faults firing or not firing, then, it makes no difference whether I access the results array directly or use an NSFetchedResults controller; its the MOC that's managing this.

Comment: Of course, this raises another question.  For NSFetchedResultsController to be efficient when operating against a large data set, it must additionally be using the setFetchLimit and setFetchOffset mechanisms under the hood, i.e. to limit the records being returned...which is why TechZen said I should mimic this behavior when not using NSFetchedResultsController.  I always was the slow one in the room.  Many thanks for TechZen and Scott for clarifying this matter.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what optimizations NSFetchedResultsController performs under the hood. However, you could probably run a few tests using Instruments and manually setting a batch limit on your fetch request. It seems unlikely that FRC uses set limit and offset as you can always call [aFRC fetchedObjects] to receive the entire list of objects targeted by the fetch request as a subclass of NSArray.

Comment: Hmmm...good point.  I did say I was a newbie, didn't I? :)  I think I will set up an experiment to understand what FRC is doing re: performance.  While this has no bearing on using it with UITableViews, which is a given, it does seem relevant for deciding whether to use it in other places.  Thanks again for your time and patience as I fumble around with these new concepts.

Comment: One thing that probably isn't clear is how results in the array initially returned as a faults get turned into objects. The FRC returns a special array implementation that fires an object's fault when it is retrieved. So, as you retrieve indexes in the array, they go from faults to objects.

Answer (score 3):

You use the `fetchOffSet` method to have the fetch request start the next batch fetch after the point you've already fetched.